# Communicating resource increase or decrease in a normalized way

Tags: communication

Consider I have a system where I am reducing the amount of a certain resource $R$ required to get the same result. If the old system uses $r_1$ $R$ and the new system uses $r_2$ $R$, I can say we have a $\frac{r_1}{r_2}$ times reduction in $R$ usage or $R$ required.

This is very intuitive when $r_1 > r_2$, e.g. we say we have a 2 times reduction in $R$ when we use half as many $R$. However, if we have a regression, it gets murkier. Imagine the new system uses 3 times as many $R$, saying we have a 0.33 times reduction in $R$ is difficult to parse. What does that even mean?!

In essence I want to use the speedup calculation (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup), for resources which could be time or other than time, with the possibility of regressions ($r_2 > r_1$), and I'm not sure of how to make sense of the result in those cases.

One possibility is to flip the division in cases where $r_2 > r_1$ and add a negative sign to indicate the regression but I'd prefer all my values, improvement and regression alike, to be normalized.

So the question is, how do I calculate "speedup" in a normalized way and communicate that when there is possibility of regression?

Comment: Huh?? In what sense is "0.33 times reduction" "difficult to parse"?  Is there a problem stating that something takes three times as many resources as something else or a third as many? Are you asking how to interpret or write about ratios of positive quantities?  What do you mean by "regression"?  (Most likely you *don't* intend its usual meaning on this site: see [regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regression).)

Comment: "The system uses 0.33 times less water". I'm having trouble with how to work that out without flipping it (3 times more). Does that make sense? What is the intuition that this is not an improvement? Yes, sorry, by regression, I mean opposite of improvement.

Comment: This sounds like a question that would be better posted on the English usage site.  Aren't you just asking how to express the concepts "A is X times B" or "B is X times A" in a simple, clear way?